# Fingerprint issue in lenovo thinkbook14 iml

Tags: lubuntu, login, lenovo, fingerprint-reader, budgie

i am using Ubuntu budgie 20.10 version, but no any fingerprint option showing in user option, how can i set my  fingerprint in Ubuntu budgie, i have lenovo think book 14 iml.

Comment: The ThinkBook14-iml uses a "tap type" fingerprint reader, which is not yet supported in any version of Ubuntu. This is a similar problem that is plaguing the fingerprint reader on my ThinkPad Carbon X1 from working.

Comment: Run `lsusb | grep "Fingerprint"` and take note of the device ID. Then check compatibility on https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html. If you find the device you're lucky. If not, I'm afraid your sensor is not (yet) compatible. Most fingerprint sensor manufacturers don't produce drivers for Linux.

Comment: You have tagged lubuntu; how does it relate?

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me. I'm using a thinkpad x1 carbon gen 6

```
$ sudo apt remove fprintd
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:uunicorn/open-fprintd
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install open-fprintd fprintd-clients python3-validity
...wait a bit...
$ fprintd-enroll
```

If `fprintd-enroll` returns with `list_devices failed:`, you can check the logs of the `python3-validity` daemon using `$ sudo systemctl status python3-validity`. If it's not running, you can enable and/or start it by substituting `status` with `enable` or `start`.

It `systemctl status python3-validity` complains about errors on startup, you may need to factory-reset the fingerprint chip. Do that like so:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop python3-validity
$ sudo validity-sensors-firmware
$ sudo python3 /usr/share/python-validity/playground/factory-reset.py

# At some of the above points you may get a 'device busy' error,
# depending on how systemctl plays along. Kill offending processes if
# necessary, or re-run the systemctl stop python3-validity command, 
# in case it has automatically been restarted, or or kill other
# offending processes.

$ sudo systemctl start python3-validity
$ fprintd-enroll
```

I got the solution from https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity